# What happens if the leading baserunner misses a base?

Tags: rules, baseball

What is the correct ruling in the following situation?

- Runners on first (R1) and second (R2)
- Batter gets a hit and is out before reaching first (fewer than three outs)
- R1 and R2 advance; R1 touches second correctly, but R2 misses third base.
- R1 and R2 continue to advance, R1 touches third correctly but R2 notices that they have missed third and tries to come back to touch.

Is R1 out for having passed R2, or can they return to third/second base?

Comment: I've attempted to copyedit this, please edit further if I've accidentally changed the meaning of your question.

Comment: This could use a little more detail: does R1 actually pass R2 on the basepath or are they still behind R2? Also, what is the fielding team doing while the runners are making a mess of it?